# How to enable and leverage OVS-DPDK in Openstack

Tags: networking, openstack, dpdk, openstack-neutron

I have successfully deployed openstack packstack (all-in-one) in single VM. I'm running Centos7 VM. Everything work well and able to instantiate VM over native OVS networking.
I plan to have OVS-DPDK enable in my openstack. I have gone through some documentation but still not clear how to enable it. I understand Openstack Queens OVS is already DPDK support.I have seen people asking the same but no answer and I would like again to request on how I can have DPDK support to be enabled over my running openstack. Few method to change neutron configuration file or by deploying SDN controller. Hope no need to redeploy..anyway further advise would be much appreciated.

```
This is my current ovs version:-
ovs-vswitchd --version
ovs-vswitchd (Open vSwitch) 2.11.0
DPDK 18.11.0
```

I really appreciated your help and support to my question.
Please assist. Thank you

Comment: @chenol openstack (even with packstack) will be using neutron plugin to send openflow messages to OVS ofctl. Hence there whether one uses packstack/openstack openflow messages are expected to be sent to OVS/OVS-DPDK. If your question is related how to setup `rather than how to enable`. there are a couple of useful links in redhat/openstack/ovs-dpdk which explains how to get started. But if your question is not `how to setup`, I humbly request to explain the same with clarity. Note, currently I am not marking this question as `insufficient data` and will wait for your edit on the question.

Comment: Hi Vipin, Noted and thank you. I'm trying to get DPDK works on my existing openstack. Current deployment leverage native OVS for the networking.

Comment: there is no DPDK or DPDK example which works with openstack. I think what you are saying is you want to use DPDK-OVS with openstack. If you are using Native OVS `no DPDK-OVS` still the procedure is the same. The openstack talks over neutron plugin as openflow to OVS `ofctl` layer. You should have a binary of OVS that is built with DPDK to use as DPDK OVS too. Where is issue, what stage in ovs-DPDK you are stuck? Please update once again I am withholding myself from tagging this as `needs improvement`. Please update correctly.

Comment: Hi @Vipin Varghese, I have DPDK installed (DPDK 18.11.0) together with OVS during packstack deployment. As I shared earlier, current openstack running over native ovs, thus to change to networking based on OVS-DPDK what should be changed? Is there specific file to edit or openstack have to be redeployed? This is where I have no clue how to do it. Thanks for your response and input.

Comment: I hope you understand having DPDK installation does not make OVS binary to OVS-DPDK binary. `you need to first ensure the OVS binary you have supports DPDK ports`. With respect to the original question posted `how to enable ovs-dpdk in openstack`, This is incorrect understanding, as openstack and ovs-dpdk are 2 separate instance which communicates over openflow. So `second please share the setup you have done to make ovs/ovs-dpdk communicate with OpenStack`. Third question `have you tried looking up in internet and blog on setting up openstack and ovs/ovs-dpdk via neutron plugin?`

Comment: Thanks for your input. As what I understand, ovs installed is already integrated with dpdk and default deployment of openstack will leverage ovs for networking and to change to ovs-dpdk would only require some changes to the neutron file. Some of the web link (1) https://01.org/openstack/blogs/stephenfin/2016/enabling-ovs-dpdk-openstack (2) https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/networking-guide/config-ovs-dpdk.html (3) https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_openstack_platform/10/html/opendaylight_and_red_hat_openstack_installation_and_configuration_guide/overview. Thanks

Comment: thank you for understanding the OVS and Openstack are 2 separate process and one needs to use neutron plugin to communicate via openflow for rules to add to OVS/OVS-DPDK. If you want to use OVS with DPDK ports the OVS binary has to be created with DPDK libraries. Hence I will update the answer, please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openstack and OVS are 2 different processes, which communicates via openflow rules. That is using neutron plugin which is used in OpenStack needs to configured for the ports in use. In OVS one needs to start with controller IP `openstack neutron controller`. Hence changes are listed as

1. use neutron or similar plugin for network configuration.
2. updated the neutron plugin config file for desired ports for OVS.
3. OVS vswitchd is started with IP address of controller.

Note: OVS binary needs to be build with DPDK libraries for having DPDK support. Do not expect by installing DPDK on the distro the OVS binary will become DPDK supported.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to confirm, do you mean that even do OVS have been installd thru openstack packstack deployment, DPDK is not supported yet? Thus I need to build DPDK lib for havg DPDK support? Should I follow this to build OVS/DPDK** https://github.com/jrfastab/OVS/blob/master/INSTALL.DPDK.md

Comment: OVS soruce code has to be specifically built with DPDK library. Depending upon OS distros you have to use `apt-get install openvswitch-switch-dpdk` (link https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/openvswitch-dpdk). The default installation as `apt-get install openswitch` will not be the binary for `ovs-dpdk`. As I have been suggesting first ensure the OVS does indeed support DPDK, then get into openstack, neutron and other. Accept and upvote.

Comment: ok thanks. I have to dig more on ths....thanks for your advise.